# How to flatten a nested lists while retaining elements of the list separated by comma in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-lists, flatten

I want to flatten a nested list I created below (or avoid creating it in the first place) for the keys of the track_ip dictionary while retaining the values separated by a comma.

I have a dataset df. I am trying to keep track of source_ip and destination_ip in a dictionary called track_ip. I also have created a column to represent the time since the last event for the specific source_ip and if the destination_ip is different compared to the last event.

For each source_ip as the key, I want a list of values referring to the destination_ip (which can be repeated). I would like to use the append() method but it would not allow it (since the value is a string) unless I wrap the values of the key in a list. When I do so I get a nested list of lists that I need to then flatten. If I flatten using the method I used I cannot retain the elements of values separated by a comma.

here is the shortened dataset:

```
df.head(10).to_dict('list')



{'source_ip': ['135.b1d10.d1c38.20',
  '135.0777d.04511.237',
  '135.0777d.04511.237',
  '135.b1d10.d1c38.119',
  '135.b1d10.13fe9.56',
  '135.b1d10.d1c38.72',
  '135.b1d10.d1c38.126',
  '135.0777d.04511.237',
  '135.0777d.04511.237',
  '135.0777d.04511.237'],
 'destination_ip': ['135.0777d.04511.237',
  '135.b1d10.13fe9.91',
  '135.b1d10.13fe9.71',
  '135.0777d.04511.237',
  '135.0777d.04511.237',
  '135.0777d.04511.237',
  '135.0777d.04511.237',
  '135.b1d10.d1c38.37',
  '135.b1d10.d1c38.112',
  '135.b1d10.d1c38.20'],
 'start_time': [1415749946,
  1415477729,
  1415702327,
  1415754478,
  1415749597,
  1415745508,
  1415754317,
  1415427333,
  1415584036,
  1415582789]}
```

here is my piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#import the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

#loop through the data
df.loc[:, 'time_since_last'] = 0
df.loc[:, 'diff_destination_ip'] = 0

last_time = dict()
track_ip = dict()

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['source_ip'] in last_time:
        #record delta time since last time under time_since_last
        df.loc[i,'time_since_last']=df.loc[i,'start_time']-last_time[row['source_ip']]
        #check if detination_ip was different for the source_ip and set value diff_destination_ip to 1
        if row['destination_ip'] not in track_ip[row['source_ip']]:
            df.loc[i,'diff_destination_ip'] = 1
    #record the current time as last time for the source_ip
    last_time[row['source_ip']] = row['start_time']
    #record destination_ip, if source_ip already present add the destination_ip to the list
    if row['source_ip'] in track_ip:
        track_ip[row['source_ip']] = [track_ip[row['source_ip']],row['destination_ip']]
        #flatten nested lists for track_ip[row['source_ip']]
        out = []
        for sublist in track_ip[row['source_ip']]:
            out.extend(sublist)
        track_ip[row['source_ip']] = out
        
    else:
        track_ip[row['source_ip']] = row['destination_ip']
```

What I am trying to get is an output for track_ip as below:

```
print(track_ip)
```

```
{'135.b1d10.d1c38.20': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.0777d.04511.237': ['135.b1d10.13fe9.91', '135.b1d10.13fe9.71', '135.b1d10.d1c38.37', '135.b1d10.d1c38.112', '135.b1d10.d1c38.20'], '135.b1d10.d1c38.119': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.b1d10.13fe9.56': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.b1d10.d1c38.72': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.b1d10.d1c38.126': '135.0777d.04511.237'}
```

The actual dataset has 3.5 e5 rows. I cannot have nested lists in track_ip.

If I flatten using the method I used I get the following output:

```
{'135.b1d10.d1c38.20': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.0777d.04511.237': ['1', '3', '5', '.', 'b', '1', 'd', '1', '0', '.', '1', '3', 'f', 'e', '9', '.', '9', '1', '1', '3', '5', '.', 'b', '1', 'd', '1', '0', '.', '1', '3', 'f', 'e', '9', '.', '7', '1', '1', '3', '5', '.', 'b', '1', 'd', '1', '0', '.', 'd', '1', 'c', '3', '8', '.', '3', '7', '1', '3', '5', '.', 'b', '1', 'd', '1', '0', '.', 'd', '1', 'c', '3', '8', '.', '1', '1', '2', '1', '3', '5', '.', 'b', '1', 'd', '1', '0', '.', 'd', '1', 'c', '3', '8', '.', '2', '0'], '135.b1d10.d1c38.119': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.b1d10.13fe9.56': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.b1d10.d1c38.72': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.b1d10.d1c38.126': '135.0777d.04511.237'}
```

If I don't use the flatten method I will get nested lists for the key '135.0777d.04511.237' as follows:

```
{'135.b1d10.d1c38.20': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.0777d.04511.237': [[[['135.b1d10.13fe9.91', '135.b1d10.13fe9.71'], '135.b1d10.d1c38.37'], '135.b1d10.d1c38.112'], '135.b1d10.d1c38.20'], '135.b1d10.d1c38.119': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.b1d10.13fe9.56': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.b1d10.d1c38.72': '135.0777d.04511.237', '135.b1d10.d1c38.126': '135.0777d.04511.237'}
```

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example (`df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')` is not reproducible), ideally in the form `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` you can get a repoducible format with `df.head().to_dict('list')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I included the first 10 rows of the dataset.

Comment: It looks like your loop is emulating a groupby? e.g. `track_ip = df.groupby("source_ip")["destination_ip"].agg(np.stack).to_dict()`

Comment: @jqurious Yes, you are right.  I suppose I can use a groupby for track_ip. However is there a flatten method to get from a nested list to a single list while retaining the elements of that list separated by a comma?

Comment: Not built in, you'd have to use one of the answers on here, there's lots. You could replace your if/else with `track_ip.setdefault(row['source_ip'], []).append(row['destination_ip'])` and avoid creating that nesting in the first place. It's simpler to just groupby/stack though.